# mysql query and implode

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, facebook, implode

I try to retrieve a array from one table What is wrong with this code?

```
$_fbexclude = mysql_query("SELECT fbempfang FROM fbinvite WHERE fbreturn = '1' ");
$fbexcludearray= mysql_fetch_array($_fbexclude);

// Convert the array 
$excludes = implode(',', $fbexcludearray);
```

From `echo $excludes;` It only gives me just the following response: `1000033xxx161,1000033xxx161` Twice the same fbempfang

Comment: You're fetching the rows only once, therefore it creates an array of only one element `$fbexcludearray["fbempfang"]`. This may cause the problem (i suppose you want to get an array of ALL the rows)

Comment: yes its correct, i want to get an array with all rows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See if the following gives you what you want (**FIXED**):

```
$_fbexclude = mysql_query("SELECT fbempfang FROM fbinvite WHERE fbreturn = '1'");
$fbexcludearray = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($_fbexclude)) {
  $fbexcludearray[] = $row['fbempfang'];
}

// Convert the array 
$excludes = implode(',', $fbexcludearray);
```

[`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) and it's siblings (`_assoc`, `_row`) only retrieve one row at a time. This means that your original code will only give you the first returned row - to work around this, we use the loop you see above.

The reason you see the same data twice is because `mysql_fetch_array()` returns a mixed indexed and associative array, which contains all the data twice over. For this reason, it is much better to use [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) or [`mysql_fetch_row()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php), as you rarely need both formats.

In fact, it is much better to use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), but the same information applies to that as well.

Comment: Fantástico, justamente o que estava procurando e precisando, esse post resolveu a minha vida, obrigado @DaveRandom.

Answer (score 3):

Use right SQL query:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`fbempfang`) as imploded from `fbinvite`  WHERE fbreturn = '1'
```

It's return string as PHP `implode(',', array(…));`

Answer (score 1):

Try this on for size:

```
$implode_arr = array();
$_fbexclude = mysql_query("SELECT fbempfang 
                           FROM fbinvite 
                           WHERE fbreturn = '1'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($_fbexclude)) {
    $implode_arr[] = $row['fbempfang'];
}

// Convert the array 
$excludes = implode(',', $implode_arr);
```

You need to loop over the `mysql_fetch_*` functions because they only return one of the result rows at a time. For more information and examples see the [manual page for `mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php).